# How many subfields of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{16})$ for which $[L:\mathbb Q]=2$?

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

I have the 16-th primitive root of unity $\zeta$ and the extension $\mathbb Q(\zeta):\mathbb Q$, I want to find the $L$ subfields of this extension for which $[L:\mathbb Q]=2$.

Could anyone tell me what these subfields are and what their structure is? I've looked for examples online that manipulate the elements but I found them confusing, could I use the fact that I know $\zeta^2$ is a primitive 8-th root of unity and $\zeta^4$ is a primitive 4-th root of unity?

Help appreciated!

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953490/bijection-between-the-quadratic-subfields-of-mathbbq-zeta-mathbbq-and); or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692645/intermediate-fields-of-cyclotomic-field-mathbbq-zeta-8-dummit-foote-14).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I understand the second one a little more, I know the galois group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/16 \mathbb Z)^*$ and is of order 8 but I am struggling to apply their method to my case. Are you able to show me where to go from there? I would be so grateful

Comment: You should describe the group $(\Bbb Z/(16))^\times$ explicitly, as product of a cyclic group of order four and a group of order two. Then describe the subgroups of order four, and their quotients. Alternatively, you might try to understand $\zeta_{16}$ in depth: what is $\zeta^4$, and what is $\zeta^8$?

Comment: I believe that the subgroups of order 4 are $C_2 \times C_2$ $\{ 1\} \times C_4 $ and $C_2 \times C_4 $, what are the subfields I can deduce from this?

Comment: Would $\mathbb Q(\zeta_8)$ be one of them?

Comment: I guess what Lubin was suggesting is that you should write down the elements of those subgroups **in terms of where they send $\zeta$!** Only then you have a chance to figure out the corresponding fixed fields. Note, there are isomorphic but non-identical subgroups, and they correspond to different intermediate fields.